# JAVA. Searching a value and displays the data

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

'm currently making a purchase program. I'm almost halfway done on it, the only thing i need is. when i Press 1 for purchase it will give me an option to input the Item Code that i stored in my inventory. And then it respectively displays the datas or values corresponds on my inputted code based on my stored products on my inventory.

PS: im new in java and i know my codes are still basic cus im still learning java on my own. And my variables are not yet changed into Arraylist cus i just found out that Arraylist is much better than a plain Array in storing collection of data.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated and welcome. Would stick on using Arraylist or Array. not Hashset or etc.. Thank you Guys!

Hope you guys could help me. Thanks!

Comment: can you show us the code of Item class and also the code you are using to seach items from arraylist?

Comment: Your description is confusing. Tell us which half you have completed and what you need help on. Also, give us some code.

Comment: You say you don't want to use HashSet, but you should probably consider it. Searching through an ArrayList for a 'icode' will take O(N) time. Using a HashSet (by overriding hashcode and equals to use the 'icode' field) will make searching O(1). This would be a necessity when creating an actual database that could store 1000s of items.

Comment: it's kinda okay now, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Item {
    public final int sku;
    public final String desc;
    public final type other_fields;

    public Item(int s, String d, type fields...) {
        // set fields
    }
}
```

or if you really want to be clever

```
abstract class Item {
    public final int sku
    // ....
}

class PinkCurtains extends Item {
    public PinkCurtains() {
        sku = 129534;
        desc = "Adorable Pink Indoor Curtains";
    }
}

class FuzzyTowel extends Item {
    public FuzzyTowel() {
        sku = 874164;
        desc = "Machine Washable Fuzzy Towel";
    }
}
```

then populate your list and search away

```
ArrayList<Item> catalog = new ArrayList<Item>(0);

for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    catalog.add(new Item(arg, arg, arg...));
}

// or

catalog.add(new PinkCurtains());
catalog.add(new FuzzyTowel());

for (Item item : catalog) {
    if (chosenItem == item.sku) {
        // do all your stuff
    }
}
```

They are called Iterables for a reason. You don't have to make classes if you don't want to. ArrayList also has searching methods, contains() and indexOf() for example:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

If you want to fill in the fields as you go you can make a class that lets you do that:

```
class Item {
    public int id;
    public float price;
}

ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<Item>(0);

do {

    Item item = new Item();

    item.id = userInput;
    item.price = userInput;

    cart.add(item);

} while (userInputting);

float total = 0;

for (Item i : cart) {
    total += i.price;
}

// using a regular for loop instead of for-each

for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
    Item item = cart.get(i);

    // or search for something particular

    if (item.id == searchID) {
        System.out.println("found item " + item.id + " with price $" + item.price);
    }

    // equivalent to

    if (ids[i] == searchID) {
        System.out.println("found item " + ids[i] + " with price $" + prices[i]);
    }
}
```

Each time the user wants to add an item, you just make a new one, fill in the fields and add it to the list.

Comment: i will consider this. thanks! but the infos are depends on the user's input not fixed. and it dpends on many items they want to store and purchase.

Comment: Just an example of how you can use ArrayList to do this kind of thing. ArrayLists are functionally like a regular array except they are of variable size and have a few bells and whistles. You can also just as soon as create an Item class and fill in the fields as the user types them in. It's just a way you can keep it all in one place.

Comment: can u show me how? pls? im getting it. all well and nuff said. Thank you!!

Comment: I added an example. Java doesn't have structs like C-derived languages but you can just as soon as make a class that only has fields.

Comment: Ok will try that later on my pc! Cus im on my phone atm. Big thanks for ur time.  How can i keep u updated?

Comment: And after all the inputs how can i search for the id of an item and displays the corresponding name, price of it?

Comment: You will just need to iterate through the list and check for it. Once you find the list item that has what you are looking for then you have all the other fields on it too. If you were not using classes, you would have to search through the id array and then use the found index on the other arrays but using a class lets you skip that step. I added an example of searching with a regular for loop instead of for-each.

Comment: I don't know about updating me, SO is warning me to avoid extended discussions in comments. Just study my example which I think has everything you need to refactor your own code to do whatever you want it to. Instead of maintaining all of your arrays, make a simple class that holds those fields and fill them in with the user input. Add them to a list and when the user is done inputting you can do whatever you want with the list.

Comment: Ya, were not using classes, but i will consider of doing those than a plain array for me to learn more. Thanks for this!!

Comment: What i mean is, if theres any other way for me to contact your or what. If i have any other concerns. Thank a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. Iterating through an array will use the same syntax for seeking, ArrayList just lets you change the size of an array as you go. And I don't know what to tell you. I don't mind helping, SO is just not set up for that. I don't see a private message feature. There's a chat but I have to go to bed.

Comment: How bout ur email either or any messenger accnt?

Comment: I mean not in SO. In any apps messenger either. Good night!